# Windows 10 remote desktop takes longer time to login first time

Tags: laptop, windows-10, remote-desktop

My home laptop is Dell inspiron with windows 7 64 bit enterprise edition ( It came with windows 8, I formatted and installed widows 7).

My office laptop is Dell with windows 10 64 bit.

My office laptop is docked in my office. I usually remote connect to my office laptop from my home laptop.

Our office use sonicwall VPN.

Nothing changed on my end as far as I know.

I don't know when it started, when ever I rdp into my office laptop the first time, it takes longer time to login.

Here is the screen shots of my steps:

```
1. After hit connect, initialize remote connection takes 1 second
2. Securing remote connection takes 3 seconds
```

[image: Securing remote connection]

```
3. After that Logon warning screen shows up
```

[image: logon warning]

```
4. After I click ok here, it takes more than 90 seconds for the first time.
5. I either has to close the rdp or it will automatically closes
6. Retry again, this time it shows earlier RDP connection for this user is still in progress, I can't remote.
```

[image: rdpwait]

```
7. I wait for a minute or two then retry this time it works faster (step 4 takes two second).
8. From this point, I can close and connect any number of time with no slowness issue.
```

will post the screen shot for step 5 and 6 tomorrow since I already pass through it and it won't happend again today.

Is there a way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I would check your event logs on the office PC because it sounds like Remote Desktop Services is waiting on another login process to complete before it can connect you to the desktop.

If you disconnect before RDS has connected you to the desktop session, you will be forced to wait before you can even attempt to connect as it is still waiting for that logon to complete.

There isn't much you can do to reset things at that point bar reboot and that requires you to be able to get on.

One final thing to note is that even whilst your user has to wait, another user may be able to connect and more than likely almost instantly in my experiences.

Answer (score 0):

Look for a wake up app to wake up your laptop at the office before logging in. Sounds like the computer has been put to deep sleep to conserve energy...?

Comment: One would think that if the laptop is in deep sleep, it wouldn't even respond to RDP session attempt which in my experience would cause the user to get rather quickly an error about not being able to connect (or something like that).

Comment: I'll try that, when I don't remote connect and try the office machine directly at office next day, it wake up normally, I am not sure whether it does take time when a remote connection try to wake up. Will keep you posted